How we can do Error handling in mutations Graphql - Hot Chocolate .NET
I have handled the errors in Graphql mutation by using this approach mentioned here https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v13/defining-a-schema/mutations
created the exceptions like below
    public class ValidationException : Exception
    {
        public ValidationException(string message) : base(message) {
         
        }
    }
    public class UnhandledException : Exception
    {
        public UnhandledException(string message) : base(message)
        {

        }
    }
    public class DatabaseConcurrencyException : Exception
    {
        public DatabaseConcurrencyException(string message) : base (message) { }  
    }

and added this exceptions on mutations like this
    public class Mutations
    {
        [Error<ValidationException>]
        [Error<DatabaseConcurrencyException>]
        [Error<UnhandledException>]
        public async Task<Structure> AddOrUpdateStructure(AddOrUpdateStructureCommand addOrUpdateStructureRequest, ISender mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await mediator.Send(addOrUpdateStructureRequest, cancellationToken);
        }

        [Error<ValidationException>]
        [Error<DatabaseConcurrencyException>]
        [Error<UnhandledException>]
        public async Task<Template> AddTemplate(AddTemplateCommand addTemplateRequest, ISender mediator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await mediator.Send(addTemplateRequest, cancellationToken);
        }

    }

but the question is there can be a lot of errors..so i need create the exception for that and then add the Error attribute not feasible for big applications.
so what is the correct way of handling the errors in mutations of graphql using hot-chocolate..?
there is not enough documentation of handling errors in graphql.
Need detailed answer of handling errors in graphql using hot chocolate nuget.
